# Loading Image from JSON file

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to load an image from a JSON file into my ionic application.

I can load messages/strings from the JSON file but can't get images to work.

I've created a codepen:

```
http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/aOpKgL?embed-id=15603
```

HTML:

`<img class="full-image" ng-src="{{item.source}}">`

Javscript:

```
.controller('announcementCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.infiniteLimit = 1;

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $http.get('')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;

        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      })
      .error(function() {
        $scope.data = [];

        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **ng-src=...** instead of **src=...** in the image tag since it's an angular directive.

Comment: Thanks, it's still not displaying the image. Any ideas? :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's got something to do within the JSON file. After a certain point it stops letting me reference things.

Comment: After the:                                                                                               "terms":[  

         ],                                                                                                                                part it stops working.